# Plotting really slow on 300k row dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm doing an EDA on a 320k rows dataset, 30 columns.

I'd like to display the distribution of variables so I try basic stuff like

`

```
for col in df.select_dtypes("object"):
    plt.figure()
    df[col].value_counts().plot.pie(autopct='%1.1f%%')
    plt.show()
```

`

My jupyter cell have been running for 10 minutes now... Is 300k "too much" ? Would using the GPU be of any help ? I noticed that it's really slow on Colab too...

I also tried `sns.pairplot(df)` but canceled after 20 min...

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: how many unique values are there for each column? Can you do `print(col)` to identify if any particular column is the bottleneck as it is iterating?

Comment: 300K rows isn't too much. It all depends on how the data is distributed. Having 1000 slices in a pie chart, however, would be a lot.  A seaborn pairplot with 30x30 subplots would be too much.

Comment: You're right, some columns making it slow. I'm stupid tho.. A pie of 320k+ URL is just ... dumb

Answer (score 1):

Instead of plotting pies of value counts, you could start by looking at indicators given by `df[col].describe()` for each column. It will give a much faster and much more complete overview of your data.

Then, if you want a visual overview, of course it depends on your data and what you are trying to understand, but you will want to start with visualizations that start by aggregating the data in some way. Think kernel density estimation over histogram, hexbin plot over scatter plot maybe.

My two cents for now, will edit if something else comes to mind or if you can give a bit more details on what you are looking at and what you want to do with it.

Comment: wouldn't it be more useful to try to clean datas first ? Coz the describe() table is kinda big, and I can see that a lot of columns are over 90% Nan.. BTW, can I ask above which percentage of NaN values would you consider a clomun as "useless" ?